# How to get/set the dialog control scrollbar range using a 32 bit number from 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF?

Tags: c++, modal-dialog, scrollbar

I would like to set the scrollbar range for 0x00000000 to 0xFFFFFFFF but I do not understand the MSDN example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getscrollinfo.

Doing this is simple for a trackbar but the explanation is either vague or misleading for scrollbars. The nTrackPos member is type int which will only give me a range of 0x0000FFFF.

```
typedef struct tagSCROLLINFO {
  UINT cbSize;
  UINT fMask;
  int  nMin;
  int  nMax;
  UINT nPage;
  int  nPos;
  int  nTrackPos;
} SCROLLINFO, *LPSCROLLINFO;
```

This code words fine for a track bar. How can I do the same thing for a scrollbar?

```
DWORD ctrl_min = 0x00000000;
DWORD ctrl_max = 0xFFFFFFFF;

DWORD ctrl_set_pos = 0;

SendMessage(trackbar_hwnd, (UINT)TBM_SETRANGEMIN, (WPARAM)FALSE, (LPARAM)ctrl_min);
SendMessage(trackbar_hwnd, (UINT)TBM_SETRANGEMAX, (WPARAM)FALSE, (LPARAM)ctrl_max);

SCROLLINFO sbi_set = { 0 };

int resp = 0;

//This code block does not work to set the scrollbar range to a 32bit number
sbi_set.cbSize = sizeof(sbi_set);
sbi_set.fMask = SIF_RANGE;
sbi_set.nMin = 0;  //ctrl_min;
sbi_set.nMax = LOWORD(ctrl_max);
sbi_set.nTrackPos = HIWORD(ctrl_max);

resp = SetScrollInfo(scrollbar_hwnd, SB_CTL, &sbi_set, TRUE);

// this code block only retrieves an integer range 0x0000FFFF
case WM_HSCROLL:
{
    int resp = 0;

    DWORD ctrl_get_pos = 0;
    
    SCROLLINFO sbi_get = { 0 };
    
    sbi_get.cbSize = sizeof(sbi_get);
    sbi_get.fMask = SIF_TRACKPOS;
   
    switch(LOWORD(wparam)) 
    {
    
    case SB_THUMBTRACK:
    {
        resp = GetScrollInfo(scrollbar_hwnd, SB_CTL, &sbi_get);

        ctrl_get_pos = (DWORD)MAKELONG(sbi_get.nTrackPos, sbi_get.nPos);
    } break;

    } // switch(LOWORD(wparam))

} break;
```

Comment: Given that there aren't enough pixels on the screen, for such scrollbars, you can simply use `0xFFFF` as the range, multiply each value you get from the scrollbars by `0x10001` and you won't be able to tell the difference.

Comment: The purpose of the scroll bar/edit box in the dialogbox is to visually change a DWORD value, which is used as a parameter for other functions . The scroll bar arrow buttons are used for fine tune adjustments. Multiplying by 0x10001 will not work for this scenario. I guess I can just use a track bar and two arrow buttons but a scroll bar is more convenient.

Comment: "The `nTrackPos` member is type int which will only give me a range of 0x0000FFFF"? What do you mean? `int` is 32 bits

Comment: @IgorTandetnik once upon a time, `int` was 16 bits. The OP seems to think that is still the case, but that is not true, as you stated.